# Using a username through out the app

Tags: jsf

I have started a new thread, as the old one went off course from the original question,

i have a login page, validating against our LDAP server, and where as before i would have the user enter a username to determine where there data is stored by the code :

```
@Override
    public String getName() {
        return getId();
    }
```

but i would like to replace the getName() bit with the username the user has already entered from the login page, and so far i have gotten confused with the options, is there a simple way of achieving this ?

Comment: Your question is incomplete, if the answers from the other question didn't sort you out. Do you intend for `getName()` to retrieve the supplied username from the login form OR do you want to simply retrieve the name of a user who has already been authenticated by another piece of code within your application?

Comment: `getName()`was used to get a username from a input text box, and then return the getId(); what i am trying to do now is get the username from a login page i have created, that authenticates the user via our LDAP server, and then returns this string as getId();

Answer (score 1):

Those answers seem pretty clear, to me anyway .There are two main options to retrieve the *authenticated* username (the user must have been previously authenticated by your app server against some database or LDAP  or the methods returns null)

1. `getRemoteUser()`
2. `getUserPrincipal()`

both methods are available by default on the `HttpServletRequest` object associated with your context. How you want to obtain the object is now a different matter.

Within a JSF Web application

1. [the first line of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5994258/1530938) provides a way to retrieve the request object within your backing bean.

2.The answer to your previous question provides the `#{request.userName}` EL to retrieve the username directly from the HttpServletRequest into your JSF view.